# Svg не отображает path при добавлении css all: revert

Tags: html, css, svg

Я использую стороннюю библиотеку `rd party UI library`, которая включает такое правило:

`* {all: revert;}`

Затем я добавляю svg, но он не отображается, поскольку ширина и высота `<path>` равны 0.
У меня нет возможности удалить `all: revert;` в коде (только переопределение).

Какой стиль нужно добавить к `<path>`, чтобы сделать его видимым?

Вот демо https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-cori-4pgfh

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* this cannot be removed  */
body * {
  all: revert; /* this added by 3-rd party library */
}

.svg-wrapper * {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.svg-wrapper path {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="svg-wrapper">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path
          d="M 10,30
                         A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
                         A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
                         Q 90,60 50,90
                         Q 10,60 10,30 z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Svg not render  when added css all:revert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69696234/7394871) от участника  [@Pavlo Oliinyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3995005/pavlo-oliinyk).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69696234/7394871

Comment: На мой взгляд полезный вопрос-ответ. Так как помогает понять, почему исчезает (не отображается) SVG при добавлении сторонних виджетов

Answer (score 4):

`all: revert;` сбрасывает данные `d` (которые теперь также являются свойством CSS), а поскольку свойства CSS всегда переопределяют атрибуты SVG, ваш `<path>` больше не содержит фигуры.

Единственное исправление, которое я смог найти, - это запустить скрипт, который копирует атрибут `d` SVG в свойство `d` CSS для всех элементов `<path>:`

```
document.querySelectorAll('path').forEach(path => {
  const data = path.getAttribute('d').replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
        cssData = `path("${data}")`;
  path.style.d = cssData;
});
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('path').forEach(path => {
  const data = path.getAttribute('d').replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
        cssData = `path("${data}")`;
  path.style.d = cssData;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* Это можно удалить  */
body * {
  all: revert; /* Здесь добавляется 3-rd party library */
}

.svg-wrapper * {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.svg-wrapper path {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="svg-wrapper">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path
          d="M 10,30
                         A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
                         A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
                         Q 90,60 50,90
                         Q 10,60 10,30 z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69704670/7394871) от участника  [@Sphinxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869660/sphinxxx).</sub>